# How to save autocomplete values automatically?

Tags: javascript, ajax, data-mining

How can I save the autocomplete values that show up after typing something in a textbox?
See [here](http://www.myschool.edu.au/)
(Type 2440 in the lower text box as an example)

Where it says 'search by suburb' I need to enter a postcode to see the "Suburb, State, Postcode" format they accept as autocomplete values (otherwise doesn't work).
So I want to send a bunch of postcodes automatically and save the 'autocomplete values' (or 'suggestion values') that show up for that particular postcode.

I thought I could do it with javascript from the Firebug console to trick the site into thinking that it's the user typing the postcode and saving the return data rather than showing it like a suggestion. But I couldn't go too far.

What do you think?

By the way nothing illegal or unethical here.

Answer (score 0):

if you have firebug then you can simply look at the ajax requests and copy the json from the response tab.

here's what's returned for 2440

```
> {
>     "d": [
>         "{\"First\":\"Aldavilla,NSW,2440\",\"Second\":\"Aldavilla,NSW,2440\"}",
>         "{\"First\":\"Alstonville,NSW,2477\",\"Second\":\"Alstonville,NSW,2477\"}",
>         "{\"First\":\"Ballina,NSW,2478\",\"Second\":\"Ballina,NSW,2478\"}",
>         "{\"First\":\"Ballina East,NSW,2478\",\"Second\":\"Ballina
> East,NSW,2478\"}",
>         "{\"First\":\"Bangalow,NSW,2479\",\"Second\":\"Bangalow,NSW,2479\"}",
>         "{\"First\":\"Banora Point,NSW,2486\",\"Second\":\"Banora
> Point,NSW,2486\"}",
>         "{\"First\":\"Barrington,NSW,2422\",\"Second\":\"Barrington,NSW,2422\"}",
>         "{\"First\":\"Baryulgil,NSW,2460\",\"Second\":\"Baryulgil,NSW,2460\"}",
>         "{\"First\":\"Bayldon,NSW,2452\",\"Second\":\"Bayldon,NSW,2452\"}",
>         "{\"First\":\"Bellbrook,NSW,2440\",\"Second\":\"Bellbrook,NSW,2440\"}",
>         "{\"First\":\"Bellingen,NSW,2454\",\"Second\":\"Bellingen,NSW,2454\"}",
>         "{\"First\":\"Bentley,NSW,2480\",\"Second\":\"Bentley,NSW,2480\"}",
>         "{\"First\":\"Bexhill,NSW,2480\",\"Second\":\"Bexhill,NSW,2480\"}",
>         "{\"First\":\"Bilambil,NSW,2486\",\"Second\":\"Bilambil,NSW,2486\"}",
>         "{\"First\":\"Bingara,NSW,2404\",\"Second\":\"Bingara,NSW,2404\"}",
>         "{\"First\":\"Blakebrook,NSW,2480\",\"Second\":\"Blakebrook,NSW,2480\"}",
>         "{\"First\":\"Boambee,NSW,2450\",\"Second\":\"Boambee,NSW,2450\"}",
>         "{\"First\":\"Bobin,NSW,2429\",\"Second\":\"Bobin,NSW,2429\"}",
>         "{\"First\":\"Bogangar,NSW,2488\",\"Second\":\"Bogangar,NSW,2488\"}",
>         "{\"First\":\"Boggabilla,NSW,2409\",\"Second\":\"Boggabilla,NSW,2409\"}",
>         "{\"First\":\"Bonalbo,NSW,2469\",\"Second\":\"Bonalbo,NSW,2469\"}",
>         "{\"First\":\"Bonville,NSW,2441\",\"Second\":\"Bonville,NSW,2441\"}",
>         "{\"First\":\"Boomerang Beach,NSW,2428\",\"Second\":\"Boomerang
> Beach,NSW,2428\"}",
>         "{\"First\":\"Boomi,NSW,2405\",\"Second\":\"Boomi,NSW,2405\"}",
>         "{\"First\":\"Booral,NSW,2425\",\"Second\":\"Booral,NSW,2425\"}",
>         "{\"First\":\"Bowraville,NSW,2449\",\"Second\":\"Bowraville,NSW,2449\"}",
>         "{\"First\":\"Broadwater,NSW,2472\",\"Second\":\"Broadwater,NSW,2472\"}",
>         "{\"First\":\"Brunswick Heads,NSW,2483\",\"Second\":\"Brunswick
> Heads,NSW,2483\"}",
>         "{\"First\":\"Bulahdelah,NSW,2423\",\"Second\":\"Bulahdelah,NSW,2423\"}",
>         "{\"First\":\"Bungwahl,NSW,2423\",\"Second\":\"Bungwahl,NSW,2423\"}",
>         "{\"First\":\"Burringbar,NSW,2483\",\"Second\":\"Burringbar,NSW,2483\"}",
>         "{\"First\":\"Byabarra,NSW,2446\",\"Second\":\"Byabarra,NSW,2446\"}",
>         "{\"First\":\"Byron Bay,NSW,2481\",\"Second\":\"Byron
> Bay,NSW,2481\"}",
>         "{\"First\":\"Cabbage Tree Island,NSW,2477\",\"Second\":\"Cabbage
> Tree Island,NSW,2477\"}",
>         "{\"First\":\"Carool,NSW,2486\",\"Second\":\"Carool,NSW,2486\"}",
>         "{\"First\":\"Cascade,NSW,2453\",\"Second\":\"Cascade,NSW,2453\"}",
>         "{\"First\":\"Casino,NSW,2470\",\"Second\":\"Casino,NSW,2470\"}",
>         "{\"First\":\"Chatsworth Island,NSW,2469\",\"Second\":\"Chatsworth
> Island,NSW,2469\"}",
>         "{\"First\":\"Chillingham,NSW,2484\",\"Second\":\"Chillingham,NSW,2484\"}",
>         "{\"First\":\"Clarenza Via Grafton,NSW,2460\",\"Second\":\"Clarenza
> Via Grafton,NSW,2460\"}",
>         "{\"First\":\"Clunes,NSW,2480\",\"Second\":\"Clunes,NSW,2480\"}",
>         "{\"First\":\"Coffee Camp,NSW,2480\",\"Second\":\"Coffee
> Camp,NSW,2480\"}",
>         "{\"First\":\"Coffs Harbour,NSW,2450\",\"Second\":\"Coffs
> Harbour,NSW,2450\"}",
>         "{\"First\":\"Coffs Harbour Jetty,NSW,2450\",\"Second\":\"Coffs
> Harbour Jetty,NSW,2450\"}",
>         "{\"First\":\"Collins Creek,NSW,2474\",\"Second\":\"Collins
> Creek,NSW,2474\"}",
>         "{\"First\":\"Comboyne,NSW,2429\",\"Second\":\"Comboyne,NSW,2429\"}",
>         "{\"First\":\"Condong,NSW,2484\",\"Second\":\"Condong,NSW,2484\"}",
>         "{\"First\":\"Coolongolook,NSW,2423\",\"Second\":\"Coolongolook,NSW,2423\"}",
>         "{\"First\":\"Coopernook,NSW,2426\",\"Second\":\"Coopernook,NSW,2426\"}",
>         "{\"First\":\"Coorabell,NSW,2479\",\"Second\":\"Coorabell,NSW,2479\"}"
>     ] }
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks herostwist, but I couldn't find where you did this from. Where can I see the ajax requests and where is the response tab? (I use the latest Firebug with Firefox 3.6.16). How can I automate this for more postcodes?

Comment: in the console tab make sure you have showxmlhttprequests checked and you should see a request to http://www.myschool.edu.au/AutoComplete.asmx/GetSuburbNames after you have used the aoutocompleter.

Comment: if you want to see an example of how to extract the locations see here: http://jsfiddle.net/NYguK/